# Automatic way of keeping track of different environment versions?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, jira, confluence, environments

In my project we use JIRA + Confluence + Teamcity.

We have different environments (dev, systest, beta, integration, live). We make CI and our build progress from one environment to other.

If I want to see the version I only need to access

```
http://dev.xxxxx.blah:9000/version.xml
http://systest.xxxxx.blah:9000/version.xml
```

That xml contains

```
<buildInfo>
 <buildNumber>46</buildNumber>
</buildInfo>
```

Now we track different versions in a whiteboard that is manually updated... not very reliable. I was thinking to do an easy web app that get xml for different environments and presents results in a table or similar.

But I am wondering... **is there any JIRA or Confluence or Teamcity plugin that do this already?**.

If not, **is there any application that easily do this?**

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity can use your custom build numbers (with version string or something) instead of its own sequence-generated ones. In my team, we're setting our own version number, based on source control changeset number as a build number and we can see the version of currently deployed artifacts right in the TeamCity, next to the last run "Deploy to XYZ" stage - see i.e. [JetBrains' own TeamCity instance for examples](http://teamcity.jetbrains.com/) (see "TeamCity C# runner plugin" for example).

All you need to do is to have this TeamCity command in your build/deployment process output:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber '<buildnum>']
```

See [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildNumber).